# Get row filtering by max(col) in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm using postgresql and I'm unfamiliar with it. This code works but I was wondering if I could write it in a more straightforward way. Here I join bar to join bar in a subquery. I was hoping there's something simple like `select * from bar group by baz using max(z)`

```
select *
from foo f
join bar b on(f.baz=b.baz AND b.z in (select max(z) from bar group by baz))
where uid1 = 120
```

Comment: Is `uid1` a column of `bar` or `foo`? The best query depends on it. Postgres version and table definitions would also be instrumental.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter uid is from bar but really I was just learning how to do this commonly written line in a more simple way. It appears `explain` prefers the distinct/orderby method and I do too.

Comment: What the Postgres query planner prefers (and you get to see with `EXPLAIN`), very much depends on the complete picture. With big tables, your query can be much faster one or the other way. Doesn't matter much with small tables. But performance optimization is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (f.baz) *
from foo f join
     bar b
     on f.baz = b.baz 
where uid1 = 120
order by f.baz, b.z desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39748593/939860) is almost but not quite correct. There is a subtle difference between `max(b.z)` and `ORDER BY b.z DESC` if the column can be `NULL`. Often overlooked and cause for much headache.

This can bite you, *even with a column `b.z` defined `NOT NULL`*. An outer join can introduce `NULL` values for the column. Wouldn't be effective in this simple query, but can be in more complex queries.

While aggregate functions like `min`, `max` or `count` ***ignore*** `NULL` values, those *have to* be dealt with somehow when the same column is used in the `ORDER BY` clause.
In default sort order `NULL` values sort *last*. When the sort order is reversed with `DESC`, `NULL` values sort *first*. It must be that way to stay consistent.
Hence, you get a row with `baz IS NULL` from `DISTINCT ON` if any `NULL` value is in the set of peers, where you would get the greatest not-null value (if any) from `max(b.z)`. Most probably not what you want. You can fix it with **`NULLS LAST`**:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Plus, while using `SELECT *`, you would not want to return the join column `baz` twice - guaranteed to be identical. The `USING` clause comes in handy, it only returns the column *once*.

So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (baz) *
FROM   foo f
JOIN   bar b USING (baz)
WHERE  uid1 = 120   -- where from?
ORDER  BY baz, b.z DESC NULLS LAST;
```

`NULLS LAST` won't hurt, even if there are no `NULL` values - unless you actually want `NULL` values to prevail.

Detailed explanation for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

#### Faster

Since `uid1` is from `baz` ([as commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748563/get-row-filtering-by-maxcol-in-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment66797047_39748563)), this query is typically faster for big tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM   foo f
JOIN  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (baz) *
   FROM   bar
   WHERE  uid1 = 120
   ORDER  BY baz, z DESC NULLS LAST
   ) b USING (baz);
```

Depending on table definition and data distribution, there may be even faster query techniques:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: My actual code does `where uid1 = :uid OR uid2=:uid` uid is either the current logged in user or whoever the admin is impersonating. The column is never/not null

Comment: @acidzombie24: If you are interested in performance optimization I suggest you write a new question where you provide exact table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) and your Postgres version along with your actual query. The simplification here may be misleading. You can add a comment here to get my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
 You can have below query,

```
SELECT * FROM foo f
INNER JOIN (SELECT baz, MAX(z) FROM bar GROUP BY baz) b
ON (f.baz = b.baz)
WHERE f.uid1 = 120;
```

Just joining bar with the MAX(z) derived and populating your required value.
uid1 must be from foo table and since f is used as alias, if not change to b.uid1

Comment: I wasn't clear with my original code bc I was lazy and just put * but I need to access the entire row (bar or b.*). Which is why I joined bar with itself.